# Changing the image on the Windows XP Start button

Tags: windows, images, skin

I am trying to change the image on the Windows XP similar to [eldergeek](http://www.theeldergeek.com/change_text_on_xp_start_button1.htm). While this works fine for changing the text in the start button, I am having difficulty changing the windows logo to another image.

The problem is that I don't know how to save the bitmap while keeping the transparency intact. Does anyone know of any free software that can save bitmaps with transparency that windows will respect?

I got this working with some slight modifications to the answer listed below:

The bitmap is in folder 143 (not 142). Axialis IconWorkshop worked, IcoFX didn't. If you want to use only a bitmap (and not text), you have to change the value of the "start" string to a single space. If you use an empty string, you get weird results.

The start string is typically within folder #37 in the string table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download **[Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)**
2. Locate explorer.exe in C:\WINDOWS. Copy the file and name it explorer1.exe.
3. Run Resource Hacker. Select File, then Open, and select C:\WINDOWS\explorer1.exe.
4. Collapse the String Table folder and expand the Bitmap folder, then select folder 142 and right-click on 1033. Select “Replace Resource“, then click on “Open file with new bitmap“. Select a Bitmap picture (.bmp extension) with a size of 25 pixels by 20 pixels. Click the Replace button. **if you would like to make a bitmap image with transparency, you will need an advanced icon making program such as [Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/).**
5. Select File, then Save.
6. Exit Resource Hacker and click on the start button and select “Run…“. Type in “regedit” without quotes.
7. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.
8. Double click on the Shell entry and input “Explorer1.exe” without quotes in “Value data“.
9. Restart Windows.

*[Source](http://www.technipages.com/change-windows-xp-start-button-text-and-logo.html)*

Edit: **[IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/)** might do the job as well:

> Import / export images (transparency
>   also) from bmp, jpg, gif, png, jp2

Comment: For those that find this later, IcoFX cannot save to a bitmap, and thus was unable to meet my needs. It could however, edit icons right out of an exe or dll. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save to PNG or GIF format. Paint.net or GIMP will do the trick. JPG doesn't do transparency. EDIT: neither does bitmap.

Comment: I thought it had to be a .bmp. Will it work if I use a .PNG?

Comment: I'm not sure, what resource editor are you using to change the image?

Comment: OK, Molly got it covered.